# How to update NSMutableArray values inside the NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have one NSMutableDictionary Test = {key1:[0,0,0,0],key2:[0,0,8,0,0]}..here Arrays are NSMutableArray.I need to update some values in array inside the dictionary.For Example.

```
- (IBAction)update(id)sender {
      UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
      int test = 9;
      UIView *contentView = button.superview;
      UIView *viewWithTag16 = [contentView viewWithTag:16];
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.dataColletionview indexPathForCell: (DataColletionViewCell *)[[sender superview]superview]];
      NSLog(@"flag values...%@",_flag);
      ...................... 
      .....................
     }
```

Here indexpath.row will be a variable integer and the the flag will be like key1,key2,key3 similar to keys in dictionary.Based on the integer a values and _flag values i need to update the array value inside dictionary.Example _flag = key2 and indaexpath.row = 3. i need to update test integer value to second array(key2) 3rd position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the array from you dictionary using below way:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [yourDict ObjectForKey:@"key2"];
```

Replace the object in your array by below way:

```
[arr replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:newObject];
```

If you want to put it back,

```
[yourDict setObject:arr forKey:@"key2"];
```

Comment: i got it that one i need to update that array in my mutable dictionary

Comment: It will automatically reflected in your dictionary. Because they are of reference type.

Comment: I have also shown the way to put array back to dictionary.

Comment: I put one more question would you help me.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24306138/how-to-set-activity-indicator-for-a-view-when-click-the-table-cell