# How to set activity indicator for a view when Click the table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am developing one iPad application using story board.In my view controller one table is set as the left side and one more view is set as the right side.I need to set one activity controller above the right side view.Which need to start animating when i click the right side table cell and need to stop after 1s.I am using 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' function for select table cell.How i will set activity indicator for my situation.

Comment: Sorry, I don't fully understand the question. There's a right side tableView appeared from nowhere, some animation and activity indicator. You'll need to clarify what you are trying to do, how you do it and which part doesn't work for you.

Comment: @A-Live consider our view controller is divided in to two parts.I put one table view in right part and one uiview in left side.In table view have some values.If i click the table cell  one activity indicator is appear above the left side view. The following steps i did 1) drag and drop the activity indicator to the left side view. 2) created outlet for acidity indicator. 3)put this code [self.acvityindicator startAnimating] in didSelectRowAtIndexPath function.But the activity indictor is not appear when i click the table cell.

Comment: @iphonic Activity indicator is not appear when i click the table cell

Answer (score 1):

In didSelectRowAtIndexPath method you could make a call to below function:-

```
-(void)setActivityIndcator:(UIView *)view
{
  transparentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  transparentView.frame = view.frame;  //Provide frame of right side view.
  transparentView.alpha = 0.5;   //To provide transparent look and feel.

  activityInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

  activityInd.frame = CGRectMake(transparentView.frame.size.width/2, transparentView.frame.size.height/2, 50, 50);  //Change as you want it to be

  [transparentView addSubview:activityInd];

  [activityInd startAnimating];

  [self performSelector:@selector(stopIndicator) withObject:self afterDelay:1];
}

-(void)stopIndicator  //This method will be called after delay and would remove view and activityInd
{
  [activityInd stopAnimating];

  [activityInd removeFromSuperview];
  [transparentView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Also you could create a subclass of it and use it in any viewcontroller by creating it's object. That why u don't need to write down all function everytime.

Comment: It is not working.I am using storyboard what is the use of following codes transparentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  transparentView.frame = view.frame;  //Provide frame of right side view.
  transparentView.alpha = 0.5;   //To provide transparent look and feel.

  activityInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];

  activityInd.frame = CGRectMake(transparentView.frame.size.width/2, transparentView.frame.size.height/2, 50, 50);  //Change as you want it to be

Comment: I think he meant that you need to add `transparentView` on top of some view where you want the indicator to appear. The fact that you are using storyboard is irrelevant.

Comment: @A-Live your right I want you to have a view on which we appear a activity indicator. This way user will be indicated that not to tap on screen as activity indicator is animating and also for look 'n' feel.

Answer (score 0):

use this in this method
didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView = 
[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
activityView.frame = CGRectMake(120, 230, 50, 50);
[self.view addSubview:activityView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` of TableView and write the following code into it

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activity = 
[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
activity.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/2, 50, 50);
[self.view addSubview:activity];
[activity startAnimating];
```

Stope this when your work is done and remove it from the view